# scale tag in uwsim

Tags: ros, ubuntu, mesh, ubuntu-precise, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to use scale tag for my mesh file in urdf that is loaded in uwsim, i tried like standard urdf in mesh tag, but it doen't work, also tried with inside collision tag that i got parsing error. anybody knows how it is possible to scaling mesh files in urdf for uwsim?
Also is it possible to use xacro in uwsim or not?
Thanks in advance.

my urdf:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="visual">
<link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
         <!--   <cylinder length="0.6" radius="0.2"/> -->
         <!--   <mesh filename="robot/cube_20k.stl" scale="4 4 4"/> -->
          <mesh filename="robot/ARM5E/ARM5E_part0.osg" scale="6 6 6"/>
     </geometry>
</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196870/scale-tag-in-uwsim/) by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Scale tag is working in URDF meshes since May 21,  version 1.3.1-1. Please check if you have an older version because it should be working. As an example:

```
<mesh filename="robot/ARM5E/ARM5E_part0.osg" scale="3 3 3"/>
```

About xacro, URDF can be generated through xacro, but UWSim does not allow xacro input yet, it's still in TO-DO list.

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2014-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on 2014-11-06**:
Thank you, it works now, the problem was i installed from binary at first and scale tag didn't work, I installed from source and now it works.